# R- start a new line after a semi colon?

Tags: r

I have the code as below that generates an output with semicolons -

```
b <- capture.output(
for(i in 1:3){
str_i <- paste("take",i,";")
cat(str_i)
}
)
```

and this gives the output as below -

```
> b
[1] "take 1 ;take 2 ;take 3 ;"
```

but the output that I need is as below -

```
take 1;
take 2;
take 3;
```

by using cat, I was able to remove level number[1] and "" but still I need to separate the line by semicolon.

```
> cat(b)
take 1 ;take 2 ;take 3 ;
```

I tried rbind to see whether I can make it vertically, but can't remove the level number/identifier. After I tried multiple things, I'm not sure whether it is doable at this point. Any advice will be very appreciated.

```
> rbind(str_1,str_2)
      [,1]      
str_1 "take 1 ;"
str_2 "take 2 ;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
s <- paste0("take ", 1:3, ";", collapse="\n")
cat(s, "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The newline is encoded as `"\n"` in R, just as with many, many other languages. Simply use `";\n"` instead of `";"`.